# Set removeAll is removing values from original source

Tags: set

`SetA.removeAll(setB)` removes the value even from map it is fetched from.

```
Map<String,set<String>> MapOne = new Map<String,set<String>>();

set<String> one= new set<String>();

set<String> two = new set<String>();

set<String> three = new set<String>();


one.add('One');
one.add('Two');
MapOne.put('A',one);

two = MapOne.get('A');
three.add('One');
three.add('Four');
three.add('Five');

system.debug('value is-->' +MapOne);
two.removeAll(three);
system.debug('value is-->' +MapOne);
```

After removeAll even the value from Map is removed. Can somebody explain why it is modifying the original map also.

Comment: That is because all values are getting passed by [reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/05/passing-parameters-by-reference-and-by-value-in-apex.html).

Answer (score 5):

Apex collections are always passed by reference meaning that it is just a pointer to the original collection. If you want to create a new instance of a collection that can be independently modified you will want to use the `clone()` method on the collection. More information is available at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm